# GORM golang on delete SET NULL

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm working with the gorm library, which is an ORM for Go. I'm adding a foreign key like so, but it seems to just keep the CASCADE setting.

I want the SET NULL setting.

```golang
DB.Model(&models.User{}).AddForeignKey("chat_uuid", "chats(chat_uuid)", "SET NULL", "SET NULL")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code works fine, make sure you delete your table then run migration again, because gorm migration don't delete or change saved columns or indexes.